# Accidentally removed libselinux and nothing works

Tags: linux, centos7, yum, selinux

I have accidentally removed libselinux on centos 7.4 and am unable to install it again and all commands fail. How do i recover?

ls: error while loading shared libraries: libselinux.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

yum install libselinux-2.5-12.el7.x86_64
There was a problem importing one of the Python modules
required to run yum. The error leading to this problem was:

libselinux.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I do have files as below.

[root@localhost lib64]# locate libselinux.
/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/libselinux.conf
/usr/lib64/libselinux.so.1

Answer (score 2):

Boot the install media into rescue mode. Use  `yum --installroot=/mnt/sysimage` to install the package in the broken system's root.  Should that not work, you can download the rpm, extract this library, and copy it into place.

Or, backup data on the host, and build a new VM from scratch.

(And to prevent future occurrences: avoid becoming the root user.)

Comment: if you have similar system or install it on VM and then copy the file to server doing rsync or scp, hope it resolves

Comment: I can't run yum/rpm. How can i install ?

Comment: Like I said in my answer, you can rebuild a new operating system from scratch. It is possible to extract a libselinux from an rpm package (with rpm2cpio) or from a working system, but its tricky as you need to be in rescue mode.

Answer (score 0):

Very late reply, but I am sure it might help others.
I too faced this problem recently, where I moved the libselinux.so.1 file on CentOS.
After running the command "ldconfig", the problem was solved for me